# unable to call web services from java script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services

i have created a `web services`, then i added the url of that web services in my `asp.net` `webform` .  for calling it from `javascript`, i have to add the path of web services . 
like this (i found somehere on internet) `<asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/MySampleService.asmx" />`

but after adding service refrance to my site i cound not find any file with extension **.asmx**

i have seperatlly created the web services and my `asp` web form.
is there mandatory to my asp web form and `web services` in same project for calling web services from `java script`

Comment: can you show me `javascript` code?

Comment: sir first i have to provide the path . there is no .asmx file . 
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="????" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
unable to find .asmx .

Comment: your services available on your same domain?

Comment: Did you create a .asmx file? Are you sure you have the path to it correct?

Comment: Check this link. It describes how to call a we service using XmlHttp with JavaScript.http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/WebServices/55_Consuming_Webservices_via_XMLHTTP_protocol.aspx